# running .txt file using .py script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to read and perform a function cat(filename) on a file small.txt in my windows terminal. The python script is named hello.py. Running hello.py small.txt isn't showing up the result. The script code is as follows:

```
    import sys
    def cat(filename):
        f=open (filename,'rU')
        text = f.read()
        print text
    def main():
        cat (sys.agrv[1])
    # This is the standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

   RESTART: C:\Users\WELCOME\google-python-exercises\hello.py

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\WELCOME\google-python-exercises\hello.py", line 34, in <module>
   main()
   File "C:\Users\WELCOME\google-python-exercises\hello.py", line 30, in main
   cat (sys.agrv[1])
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'agrv'
```

Comment: It is argv not agrv

Comment: You misspelled `argv` as `agrv` on line 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misspelling `agrv`. After reading the file, you are not closing it. Try this:

```
import sys

def cat(filename):    
    f = open(filename)
    text = f.read()
    f.close()
    print(text)

def main():
    cat(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would rewrite the `cat()` function using `with` statement as it takes care of closing the file.

```
def cat(filename):    
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read()
    print(text)
```

[Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) says:

> It is good practice to use the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.